# DatePickerDialog not Displaying Last Week

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-calendar, calendarview

I have implemented `DatePickerDialog` in my app and I am having the following issues with **Lollipop** only.

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```
void setDate(final EditText ed) {
    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    DatePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            monthOfYear += 1;
            ed.setText(selectedYear + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + dayOfMonth);
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    //mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Date:");
    mTimePicker.show();
}
```

I am not able to select date of last week and on pressing next it's displaying next month.

Has anyone run into a problem like this? Does anyone have a solution?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this? I am faced with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same issue as well.

It has nothing to do with min or max dates set on the datepicker...

It seems to be an issue arising from the screen size being small and thus the datepicker cuts off the last week of the month(or more if the screen in really small) and the 'days' area is not scrollable(up/down)... scrolling left/right will take you to the previous/next month...

My idea for a fix would be to make the 'days' area of the datepicker vertically scrollable but as this is a default android widget I am not sure how to go about doing this -_-

P.S. I know this is not an answer but my rep prevents me from making a comment thus this is the only option open to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Min and Max date` to your `calendar` here is a code snippet below

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar1.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                                Date date = new Date(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());
                                if (date.after(new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()))) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ProfileFirstFragment.this.getActivity(),
                                            getString(R.string.error_wrong_date_selected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }

                                dob.setText(getString(R.string.date_slash, new String[]{String.valueOf(dayOfMonth),
                                        String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1), String.valueOf(year)}));
                            }
                        },
                        1990, 0, 1); //this can be your calendar startdate when you open the calendar
                calendar.set(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), Calendar.getInstance().getMaximum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        Calendar.getInstance().getMaximum(Calendar.MINUTE), Calendar.getInstance().getMaximum(Calendar.SECOND));
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());// this will be your max date you can select
                calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -90); 
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                datePickerDialog.show();//this will be minimum date in your calendar
```

I hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

While creating `DatePickerDialog` instance, Pass the minimum date you want to alllow user.

```
    new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, 
                                     int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO
            }
    }, year, month, 1); // for current month's first day as minimum
```

and in next line, before `show` call method `updateDate`

```
     mDatePicker.updateDate(year,month,day); // for current date to set selected
```